# Webapi custom route action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

### Situation :

I've created controller class that extends ApiController and includes following methods :

```
        // GET api/Posts/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Post))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetPost(int id)
        {
           ...
        }

        // GET api/Posts/ByBoardID/2
        [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("ByBoardID")]
        public IQueryable<Post> GetByBoardID(int boardID)
        {
           ...
        }
```

The idea is to match those method to a given routes (i.e 'api/Posts/ByBoardID/2' to a GetByBoardID(int boardID) method and 'api/Posts/2' to a GetPosts(int id) method).

Here's route config :

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ByParamApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

### Problem :

Second route ('api/Posts/ByBoardID/2') cannot be matched - `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI`.

### Question :

Whats the best practice to create such 'nested' routes inside controller? I will use many controllers with the same pattern `(/{controller}/{id} and /{controller}/bySpecialParam/{id})` so I don't want to 'hardcode' such route that won't be reusable.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I ever got working such combination is by changing this

`[ActionName("ByBoardID")]`

to

`[Route("api/Posts/ByBoardID/{boardID}")]`

Never able to figure out how the ActionName attribute works so always preferred to go with Route attribute

Answer (score 1):

> This worked:

1) Provide actionName for both the methods in the controller.

```
[ActionName("DefaultAction")]
[ActionName("ByBoardID")]
```

2) In the webapiconfig class, add the following routes

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "defaultActionRoute",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                null,
                new
                {
                    action = "ByBoardId"
                });
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "defaultRoute",
                "{controller}/{id}",
                new
                {
                    action = "DefaultAction"
                });
```

Make sure you have the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();` at the end of `Application_Start()` method.